# Getting "c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler: An unexpected connection driver error occurred (Exception message: Connection reset)" in java rabbitmq

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, java-11, spring-rabbit

Getting "c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler: An unexpected connection driver error occurred (Exception message: Connection reset)" when running java project with rabbitmq

Java version - 11
rabbitmq version - 3.11.16
Erlang version - 26.0

When running java project I am getting frequent connection reset issue with localhost:5672.
I have checked that port 5672 is listening. Firewall is not blocking the port or app.

Attaching  my rabbitmq and console.

The error is logs is shown below -
accepting AMQP connection <0.28225.0> (127.0.0.1:61937 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
2023-05-25 13:55:51.840000+05:30 [info] <0.28225.0> connection <0.28225.0> (127.0.0.1:61937 -> 127.0.0.1:5672) has a client-provided name: connectionFactory#64ae105d:3
2023-05-25 13:55:51.841000+05:30 [info] <0.28225.0> connection <0.28225.0> (127.0.0.1:61937 -> 127.0.0.1:5672 - connectionFactory#64ae105d:3): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'blr'
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>   crasher:
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>     initial call: rabbit_reader:init/3
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>     pid: <0.28225.0>
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>     registered_name: []
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>     exception exit: {unexpected_message,{'EXIT',#Port<0.7023>,einval}}
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>       in function  rabbit_reader:handle_other/2 (rabbit_reader.erl, line 644)
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>       in call from rabbit_reader:mainloop/4 (rabbit_reader.erl, line 535)
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>       in call from rabbit_reader:run/1 (rabbit_reader.erl, line 457)
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>       in call from rabbit_reader:start_connection/5 (rabbit_reader.erl, line 356)
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>     ancestors: [<0.28223.0>,<0.673.0>,<0.672.0>,<0.671.0>,<0.669.0>,
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>                   <0.668.0>,rabbit_sup,<0.233.0>]
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>     message_queue_len: 0
2023-05-25 13:55:51.842000+05:30 [error] <0.28225.0>     messages: []

[image: rabbitmq]
[image: console output of eclipse]